# How can I tee the output of an ssh script?

Tags: shell, unix, tee

I want to capture the output of a shell SSH script to a file and have it on stdout at the same. I know I can use `tee` but it doesn't seem to be working as I expect in this case.

Example,

```
#!/bin/sh

ssh user@host | tee /tmp/a << EOF
echo hi
EOF
```

I expect `hi` to be in `/tmp/a`, instead it looks like `ssh` waits forever for input.

If I replace `ssh` with `cat` it works as I expect

```
#!/bin/sh

cat | tee /tmp/a << EOF
hi
EOF

Output: hi

$ cat /tmp/a
hi
```

What's the difference between `ssh` and `cat` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
ssh user@host << EOF | tee /tmp/a
echo hi
EOF
```